# ASP.Net adds nonsense characters to the URL of the page

Tags: asp.net, url, webforms

I've created a web form application with ASP.Net. I'm wondering why ASP.Net added nonsense characters between the project name and folder name of the application.

http://testServer/ProjectTest/(S(l1jqxfcri1fn12h1gb1hzjaxdtnb))/Views/Customers.aspx

in the above url, *ProjectTest* is my Project name and *Views* is the folder of the application.
how can I remove these nonsense characters **(S(l1jqxfcri1fn12h1gb1hzjaxdtnb))** from the URL. Why asp.net added them to the url automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a cookie less session.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx